# How do I replace the --D flag for pg_dumpall in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, database-backups, pg-dump

I'm trying to create a PostgreSQL backup script using [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/59847/200183) as the basis of my script. The script is:

```
#! /bin/bash

# backup-postgresql.sh
# by Craig Sanders 
# this script is public domain.  feel free to use or modify as you like.

DUMPALL="/usr/bin/pg_dumpall"
PGDUMP="/usr/bin/pg_dump"
PSQL="/usr/bin/psql"

# directory to save backups in, must be rwx by postgres user
BASE_DIR="/var/backups/postgres"
YMD=$(date "+%Y-%m-%d")
DIR="$BASE_DIR/$YMD"
mkdir -p $DIR
cd $DIR

# get list of databases in system , exclude the tempate dbs
DBS=$($PSQL -l -t | egrep -v 'template[01]' | awk '{print $1}')

# first dump entire postgres database, including pg_shadow etc.
$DUMPALL -D | gzip -9 > "$DIR/db.out.gz"

# next dump globals (roles and tablespaces) only
$DUMPALL -g | gzip -9 > "$DIR/globals.gz"

# now loop through each individual database and backup the schema and data separately
for database in $DBS; do
    SCHEMA=$DIR/$database.schema.gz
    DATA=$DIR/$database.data.gz

    # export data from postgres databases to plain text
    $PGDUMP -C -c -s $database | gzip -9 > $SCHEMA

    # dump data
    $PGDUMP -a $database | gzip -9 > $DATA
done
```

The line:

```
$DUMPALL -D | gzip -9 > "$DIR/db.out.gz"
```

is returning this error:

> psql: FATAL:  role "root" does not exist
>   /usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin/pg_dumpall: invalid option -- 'D'

When I look at the [PostgreSQL docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/app-pg-dumpall.html), there doesn't seem to be a `-D` option anymore. What should the updated command look like?

Comment: -d and -D was replaced by --inserts and --column-inserts
https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Deprecated_Features

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the modified script I ended up using to periodically backup my PostgreSQL database:

```
#! /bin/bash

# backup-postgresql.sh
# by Craig Sanders 
# this script is public domain.  feel free to use or modify as you like.

DUMPALL="/usr/bin/pg_dumpall"
PGDUMP="/usr/bin/pg_dump"
PSQL="/usr/bin/psql"

# directory to save backups in, must be rwx by postgres user
BASE_DIR="/var/backups/postgres"
YMD=$(date "+%Y-%m-%d")
DIR="$BASE_DIR/$YMD"
mkdir -p $DIR
cd $DIR

# get list of databases in system , exclude the tempate dbs
DBS=$($PSQL -l -t | egrep -v 'template[01]' | awk '{print $1}' | egrep -v '^\|' | egrep -v '^$')

# first dump entire postgres database, including pg_shadow etc.
$DUMPALL -c -f "$DIR/db.out"

# next dump globals (roles and tablespaces) only
$DUMPALL -g -f "$DIR/globals"

# now loop through each individual database and backup the schema and data separately
for database in $DBS; do
    SCHEMA=$DIR/$database.schema
    DATA=$DIR/$database.data

    # export data from postgres databases to plain text
    $PGDUMP -C -c -s $database -f $SCHEMA

    # dump data
    $PGDUMP -a $database -f $DATA
done

# delete backup files older than 30 days
OLD=$(find $BASE_DIR -type d -mtime +30)
if [ -n "$OLD" ] ; then
        echo deleting old backup files: $OLD
        echo $OLD | xargs rm -rfv
fi
```